# How to get particular POST arguments with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, request

User uploads unknown number of files to my GAE application (photos + their descriptions). The form contains

```
<input type=hidden name="{{ item.photo_imgsrc_1280 }}" id="file{{ forloop.counter }}">
<input type=hidden name="desc{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ item.description }}">
```

(name value is actually [replaced by Picasa](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/picasa/docs/web_uploader.html#feeds) with the file content)

Now in the upload handler I need to find according description for each file.
Currently I do:

```py
files_counter = 0
for argument in arguments:
    if 'localhost' in argument: # choose files only, not other fields - Picasa related approach
        files_counter +=1
        # self.request.get(argument) here returns the file
        # self.request.get('desc'+str(files_counter))) can return some other description, not 
        # related to the file above
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need different names for each hidden field. You can have the same name multiple times, and get them all. So let's change your fields a little bit:

```
<input type=hidden name="{{ item.photo_imgsrc_1280 }}" id="file{{ forloop.counter }}">
<input type=hidden name="photo" value="{{ item.photo_imgsrc_1280 }}">
<input type=hidden name="description" value="{{ item.description }}">
```

Then, get all values for the `photo` and `description` fields:

```
photo_names = self.request.POST.getall('photo')
descriptions = self.request.POST.getall('description')
```

Here, `photo_names` is a list of the field names with photos. To get the actual image fields you'd do something like:

```
photos = [self.request.POST.get(name) for name in photo_names]
```

Now, you can group them into a list of tuples `(photo, description)`, and iterate one by one:

```
data = zip(photos, descriptions)
for photo, description in data:
    # do what you need with each single photo/desc...
```

Comment: moraes, looks like I can not change the name for photo fields - it always should be equal to `{{ item.photo_imgsrc_1280 }}`, otherwise Picasa wouldn't replace that with actual file.

Comment: Edited with an alternative. There are several ways you can work around the idea to join related fields. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, just showing how you can group pairs of fields using fields with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, moreas. `photo` in my case is actual photo file, not just photo name. I've tried your approach, but even `file_size = len(photo)/(1024.0*1024.0)` doesn't work. I've used `len(self.request.get(argument))/(1024.0*1024.0)` before.

Comment: You didn't mention you were trying to find their size, or I missed something?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. I need the actual files, not just their names. Example with size is just one code which doesn't work. I think it happens so because I don't receive actual files with the form you've suggested. I have to use that fields with different names for photo files.

Comment: Should the file contents be submitted through the hidden field, like you posted, or using a file field? If you're accepting file uploads in the form, make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag.

Comment: moraes, unfortunately, I don't control how the file is submitted - Picasa does it. So, I have to have this hidden field.

Comment: moraes, if I would use `<input type=hidden name="{{ item.photo_imgsrc_1280 }}" value="{{ item.description }}">` will I get both the file and the description?

Comment: Or, probably, I can use filenames? How can I get the file name of the uploaded file? Then description field name will be equal to the filename.